# What is this red football shaped fruit?

Tags: identification

We encountered this fruit in a garden in Los Angeles.  It was on a bush. We opened a small one and it had a soft but solid interior, with no obvious seeds or pits, but again, the one we opened was very small and possibly immature.  The normal fruits were about the size of an egg.  The point at the end of the fruit shown was a common feature among the full-sized fruits.

[image]

Any idea what it is?

The bush was about waist high (maybe a little higher), and probably about the size of a kitchen or dining room table?  I have no sense of smell, but my companions didn't notice any strong scent either.

Comment: Carissa macrocarpa, Natal plum. I got this by copying your picture straight i to the PlantNet app. Cheating!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Carissa macrocarpa or Carissa bispinosa

[image: Carissa bispinosa]

Aka

Natal plum or large Num Num

Answer (score 0):

From what leaves are visible, I suspect this is likely a Camellia fruit - what you're seeing is a ripe seed case. Camellias do produce fruits, though not usually very many http://www.camellias.pics/fruit-et-graines-gb.php.

If it is Camellia, you will have seen flowers in late winter or spring - they may be red, pink, pink and white, white or yellow depending on variety.